# Decrypting with gnupg

Tags: linux, bash, gnupg

In Linux, I'm familiar with decrypting .gpg files at the command line. But it seems to me that if I want to save a decrypted file in the same folder from where the unencrypted file was, then I always have to write out the path to that folder - ie gnupg won't automatically save it there.

Eg, to decrypt a file foo.odt.gpg, which resides in folder path dir1/dir2, at the command line I would type

```
gpg -d --use-embedded-filename dir1/dir2/foo.odt.gpg
```

This would recreate file foo.odt, but it would automatically be saved in my home folder, whereas I would prefer for it to be saved in the same path as the encrypted version.   Alternatively I could achieve that by redirection:

`gpg -d dir1/dir2/foo.odt.gpg > dir1/dir2/foo.odt`

but that seems to be a long-winded way to achieve the required result. So is there a way of directly doing this, using the *--use-embedded-filename* option?

Comment: Try it with the option and see what happens.